# How to detect special characters using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div id="toggle">
∅
</div>
```

I want to detect the symbol that is in the toggle div using jquery, then change the symbol. I made the symbol above using `&#8709;`

Here is the jQuery I have tried to use but nothing is happening which leads me to believe the symbol is not being detected.

```
$("#toggle").on("click", function () {
         if ($(this).html() == "&#8709;") {
              $(this).html("O");

           }

});
```

Comment: You would have to define what "weird" characters are first..

Comment: Which characters are you wanting to convert?

Comment: What's the output of `console.log($(this).html())`?

Comment: I am trying to convert ∅ into O but I had to use &#8709; to make the special character so how do I check whats in the div against &#8709;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your code is saved as UTF-8 you can just use the character as a string

```
$("#toggle2").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).html()=='∅') {
        $(this).html("O");
    }
});
```

OR you could do it by character code

```
$("#toggle").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).html().charCodeAt(0)==8709) {
        $(this).html("O");
    }
});
```

and for extra credit... replace all occurences.

```
$("#toggle3").on("click", function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/[\u2205]/g,'o'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RmYM2/1/

Comment: YUP YOU HAVE TO USE CHARACTER CODES. NOT HTML TO DETECT SPECIAL CHARACTERS. THANKS

Comment: +1; You said it in your answer, but I'll stress it again for the OP: the first test might break if you save you source code under a different character encoding. Also, one alternate way to do that last test is with a `\u` escape sequence character: `$(this).html() == "\u2205"` (that's `8709` in hex).

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` returns the actual character so you will need to do

```
if ($(this).html() == "∅") {
```